# Filipovic: Where is it used that the world is deterministic

Tags: arbitrage, no-arbitrage-theory, zero-coupon, risk-free, proof

In this text (Damir Filipovic, *Term-Structure Models*, Springer, 2009) $P(t,T)$ denotes the price of a zero-coupon bond at time $t$ with maturity $T$. I cannot see where the proof uses the deterministic assumption. I know this result does not hold in general - but where does the argument fail if the world is not deterministic?

[image]

Comment: Where in the Wall Street Journal dated day 't' do they publish the prices of bonds as of a later date $T$. On what page ;) ? Those prices are not known in a non-deterministic world.

Comment: Ah, that is true - they don't!

Comment: In that case the unknown (stochastic) prices in these equations might be replaced by their Expectation. I.e. we would have to put $E[\cdots|t]$ around them to have a meaningful equation.